# How to change app icons & UI in flutter using flutter Inspector?

Tags: android-studio, flutter, flutter-layout

I brought an app source code from (CodeCanyon) and i want to change the side navigation drawer icon from the given one to the default hamburger icon or something.

They have given me the docs of Flutter page to change it using Flutter Inspector but i don't know how to do it.

Here is the link they send me...

https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/devtools/inspector

Help me out...

Answer (score 0):

From Android Studio, run the application in an Emulator or real device.

In the debug tab of Android Studio the 'Open DevTools' button (its icon is the Dart logo) next to the Hot Reload and Hot Restart buttons. This will launch a Dart DevTools tab.

After the new browser tab opens, click the "Try DevTools beta" button in the top right of the screen. This will take you to a new beta version of DevTools.

From there you will see what the linked page is talking about, but you must be on the latest version of Flutter.

Answer (score 0):

On 25th june flutter has declared the stable dev tool, in that if you want to change in ui then,you just have to open dev tool with your connected device and in Flutter inspector  enable the select widget mode. and in layout explorer you can changes the ui design properties. But remember one thing you can only changes in the row, column and container properties.